# How to create list based on elements from dictionary?

Tags: python, django

I have this list of dictionaries:

```
L = [{'code': 'UE', 'country': 'France'}, {'code': 'AM', 'country': 'canada'}, {'code': 'AF', 'country': 'morocco'}]
```

Is there any way to retrieve a list of codes sorted like this: `codes = ['AF', 'AM', 'UE']` ?

Comment: -1 should demonstrate what you've tried so far and why it didn't work.

Comment: @ErikAllik: i didnt even know if it is possible or not, then i got the response !

Comment: in order to know if something is possible, you have to try; if you fail, you ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a generator to `sorted`:

```
>>> codes = sorted( d['code'] for d in L )
>>> codes
['AF', 'AM', 'UE']
```

Another option is to pass a list comprehension to `sorted`, which @MartijnPieters showed to be faster in this case.

```
codes = sorted([ d['code'] for d in L ])
```

Comment: This is not a list comprehension; you have a generator expression instead.

Comment: The generator should be more efficient, I would think.

Comment: Ah thanks. I wrote list comprehension before I realized he wanted it sorted and could just use a generator.

Comment: @hunse: no, actually. The list comp is faster here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: how come?

Comment: @ErikAllik: See my answer; I've included timings and a reason

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension selecting the key you need, passing the values to the [`sorted()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
codes = sorted([d['code'] for d in L])
```

Demo:

```
>>> L = [{'code': 'UE', 'country': 'France'}, {'code': 'AM', 'country': 'canada'}, {'code': 'AF', 'country': 'morocco'}]
>>> sorted([d['code'] for d in L])
['AF', 'AM', 'UE']
```

Here, a list comprehension is faster than a generator expression:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("sorted(d['code'] for d in L)", 'from __main__ import L')
2.1713640689849854
>>> timeit("sorted([d['code'] for d in L])", 'from __main__ import L')
0.9132740497589111
```

`sorted()` requires a list to sort, so either you give it a list or it'll build a list from the iterable. Building a list from a generator expression is (a lot) less efficient than giving it a list in the first place.

Comment: So `list(<genexp>)` is not equivalent to `[<genexp>]`? Or why is it that when passing a genexp to `sorted` is slower than first converting it to a list and then passing that list?

Comment: I was going to comment on that, given that methods such as `join` are faster with a list that with a generator. For `sorted`, it also makes sense as sorting requires an actual list.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the list comprehension is faster. I tried it with a much larger list of dictionaries (i.e., 100000 elements), and then the speed difference is negligible, but still slightly in favour of the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sorted()` function with list comprehension:

```
>>> L = [{'code': 'UE', 'country': 'France'}, {'code': 'AM', 'country': 'canada'}, {'code': 'AF', 'country': 'morocco'}]
>>>
>>> sorted([d['code'] for d in L])
['AF', 'AM', 'UE']
```